# Python: Matplotlib: divider.append_axes does not work with matplotlib 3.0.0

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

Here is the code I was using with `matplotlib 2.2.3`, which correctly appended a padded axis on the right of my figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig = plt.figure(1, clear=True)
axis = plt.gca()
divider = make_axes_locatable(axis)
new_axis = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
plt.show()
fig.savefig('test.png', pad_inches=0, bbox_inches='tight')
```

However, since I updated `matplotlib` to version 3.0.0, the snippet above does not append an axis any more, but replaces the current axis. The fig.axes output shows that both axes are present:

```
[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001FEC0A38E80>,
<matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes object at 0x000001FEBD3A12E8>]
```

but there is only the new one visible in the figure overlapping and having the full size of the original axis.

The same code works OK with `matplotlib 2.2.3`. So my question is whether there are any changes in the interface of the divider introduced in version 3.0.0 or is it a bug? The  [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider.html) is scarce, but does not talk about any changes in the interface.

**Update:**

After much trouble, I've found out that the plots are shown correctly on my machine as well in `matplotlib 3.0.0`, but not saved correctly. I have localized the problem to a savefig option `bbox_inches='tight'`. So saving the figure with

```
 fig.savefig('test.png', pad_inches=0, bbox_inches='tight')
```

saves only the colorbar, while

```
 fig.savefig('test.png', pad_inches=0)
```

produces the whole figure, but with large white pads. In `matplotlib 2.2.3` both lines produce the full figure (with or without pads). My new question is then: Is `bbox_inches` broken for this kind of applications in `matplotlib 3.0.0` and how do I achive a figure with no white pads?

I have updated the MWE above to reproduce the error.

Comment: The comment by @DizietAsahi is misleading. `make_axes_locatable` has not been deprecated! (The deprecation of `LocatableAxes` is not related to that.) I also cannot reproduce the described behaviour. Running the code from the question results in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAvLa.png) for me using matplotlib 3.0.0.

Comment: Also see the [Demo Axes Divider](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_axes_divider.html) example (specifically "Plot 3") where this is working as expected in version 3.0.0.

Comment: Apologies, I should have actually tried to run the code to check if it worked, I retracted my comment

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you. Which platform are you running? My colleague running Ubuntu does not have the issue, but it is present on my Windows machine.

Comment: I'm using windows, but the documentation is built on a unix-like system and it works fine on both. I currently suspect that what you show is not a [mcve]. If you copy and run the code from the documentation, do you also observe this issue?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Indeed, I have gone through my code to get a minimal example that reproduces the error. Please see update in the question.

Comment: I see. Yep, that is broken in mpl 3.0.0. It is fixed by now via https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12363 and will be part of the next bugfix release 3.0.1, which is scheduled for first week of November.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Great, thanks. I think I'll just stay with `matplotlib` 2.2.3 till November.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I have the same problem with the append_axes also on a windows machine. Drove me crazy to figure it out and then landed here. Going back to 2.2.3. solved the issues and saved me from insanity. Windows machine with anaconda distribution